# Best way to bundle npm lib with async await

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have a react library that i wrote and internally it uses `async` and `await`. In order to bundle the lib, i’m using webpack with the babel loader + the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`. However according to the docs https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime I need to add `@babel-runtime` as a dependency.. this seems wrong to me as i don't want my users to have to install this. Is there a better way to bundle up code for users to just pull in and use?

Comment: @babel-runtime as a dependency doesn't sound like a good idea, and the output will be cluttered up without it. Using Typescript as *JS* transpiler generally results in more concise output, especially for async..await. And I'd suggest to rewrite it to raw promises for a library.

Comment: Whats the downside of users pulling in the runtime? it is fairly small and not something your users have to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You should not install as dependency, but you should as devDependency. Dev deps are only going to be installed when you run `npm install` directly inside your lib folder, which is not the case. So since you are going to distribute a transpiled file, doing that is fine.

You should also use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator